# "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Along with access is denied error while reading parquet file footer

Tags: java, footer, parquet, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

Im trying to read the parquet footer file to get the page count, So I can return the value from API that I have created. The code that i have written is as below.

```
File file = new File(filepath);

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

org.apache.hadoop.fs.path parquetFilePath = new 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.path(file.getAbsolutePath());

ParquetMetadata readFooter = 
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(conf,parquetFilePath, NO_FILTER);
```

When I execute the last line of code that is going to read the footer of the parquet file  it is giving me file not found exception (Access is denied) but actually file is present at the location. I have also given all the read and write permissions using the security tab by right clicking on the properties option

Comment: I have a same problem. Reading groups is file. But getting `FileNotFoundException("path is not a file")` for the same path. Did you resolve the problem?